# Android app activity stopping when a pop up from other app appears

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm having issues with some activities in my app - which is a game. There are 2 activities that are the game itself - `Player1` and `Players2`. In this activities, if a pop up from another app appears (e.g. Whatsapp), the activity closes and the last activity opens back up (for example, in my app, an activity called `ChooseLevel` or `ChooseGameType`.

I think it has to do with my `onStop` and `onPause` methods, where I call `finish();` to these activities. **Which one should I change in order that a popup that comes will not close the activity?** Because I do want it to close when the app is no longer showing on screen, but stay when a popup comes along.

Comment: Do you have any code examples or stacktraces?

Comment: Why are you finishing an activity during `onPause` or even `onStop`? A pop-up will call `onPause`, and if the OS kills your app on its own `onStop` and `finish` are ran anyway

Comment: There's no need to call finish on either of those callbacks.

Comment: @cricket_007 I now got the difference, but if my app is still working but not showing (not foreground nor background), so `onStop` does not call finish right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a neat but critical difference between `onPause()` and `onStop()`. From the [activity docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

**onPause():**

> Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity. This is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data, stop animations and other things that may be consuming CPU, etc. Implementations of this method must be very quick because the next activity will not be resumed until this method returns.
>   Followed by either onResume() if the activity returns back to the front, or onStop() if it becomes invisible to the user.

**onStop():**

> Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because another activity has been resumed and is covering this one. This may happen either because a new activity is being started, an existing one is being brought in front of this one, or this one is being destroyed.
>   Followed by either onRestart() if this activity is coming back to interact with the user, or onDestroy() if this activity is going away.

So you have two scenarios where you have to decide on how to proceed with your app. If you do not want to call `finish()` on your app when another `Activity` does not fully cover your app in this case for example a `Dialog` then you have to remove your `finish()` call in `onPause()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error must be in `onPause()`, because that method is always been called in Android when the app is not in foreground anymore. So if there is an activity showing from another app, like WhatsApp, `onPause()` is being called. So to avoid closing your app remove the `finish();` call from there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `onPause()` method where you call `finish()`. When another application is showing `onPause()` will be called for sure, because your app is actually during pause state. As other users have already pointed out, avoid to call `finish()`. Also, it's a bad practice and pointless to call `finish()` in `onStop()` method.